# loading gcs file into google big query gives permission error

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

I am trying to load gcs csv file into google big query table using goole big query node module apis.
I am running this script -

```
'use strict'
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage')
const { BigQuery } = require('@google-cloud/bigquery')
const projectId = 'bigqueryproject1-279307'
let keyFilename = './credentials/client_secret.json'
const storage = new Storage();
function main(datasetId = 'my_dataset', tableId = 'my_table') {

    const bucketName = 'myanalysisbucket'
    const filename = 'https://storage.cloud.google.com/myanalysisbucket/LowestTR.csv?authuser=1'

    async function loadCSVFromGCS() {
        const bigqueryClient = new BigQuery({ projectId, keyFilename })
        const datasetId = >babynames>
        const tableId = 'GCStable'
        const metadata = {
            sourceFormat: 'CSV',
            skipLeadingRows: 1,
            schema: {
                fields: [
                    { name: 'TaskRouteName', type: 'STRING' },
                    { name: 'MessageID', type: 'STRING' },
                ],
            },
            location: 'US',
        };
    enter code here
        // Load data from a Google Cloud Storage file into the table
        const [job] = await bigqueryClient
            .dataset(datasetId)
            .table(tableId)
            .load(storage.bucket(bucketName).file(filename), metadata);
```

Since, i made the file public but i am getting access denied error when running the script.

Comment: Did you try using you filename as "gs://<your-bucket>/<path>/<your-file>" ?